# Google Cloud Linux VM won't allow HTTP access event though firewall is configured

Tags: .net, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, vpc

I recently created a VM instance at Google Cloud with the O.S. being a Ubuntu 18.04.5 and the instance seems pretty ok. I cloned a git repository and put a .NET Core API to run locally as it can be seen in the screen capture bellow.

[Terminal running application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQsA4.png)

I then added a firewall rule to the Virtual Machine VPC allowing HTTP connections to be done through these ports as the screen capture bellow shows.

[VPC Firewall configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEmri.png)

As it can be seen, it should be applied to all instance in the network from every source and I made sure to open it outbound and inbound while trying to troubleshoot. Anyway, when i try to access it (Swagger UI) with my browser it says that it isn't able to connect and even telnet command is running into timeout.

May I have to do any configuration else? Am I misleading something? What could it be?

Comment: Your server is listening on `localhost` which means only applications running inside the VM can connect. Change to `0.0.0.0` which means listen for connections on all network interfaces.

Comment: That was exactly it John! Thanks you so much!

Comment: Post an answer showing the application changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For posterity searches, all it took was to change my launchSettings to force my server to listen on `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`. To achieve that, I update my launchSettings.json file from:

```
"Api": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "https://localhost:44395/",
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44395/",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```

to:

```
"Api": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "https://0.0.0.0:44395/",
  "applicationUrl": "https://0.0.0.0:44395/",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```